# Absolute paths lead to "Error: Cannot find module" since introduction of native TypeScript support in Cypress@4.4.0

Tags: typescript, cypress, tsconfig

### Project

I have a web-app with about 100 ui tests and want to get rid of the cypress-webpack-preprocessor, as typescript support was added natively in [Cypress@4.4.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support.html#Install-TypeScript). I updated to the newest version of Cypress, but it is not possible to use absolute paths in my tests anymore - I guess this should be possible.

### Problem

While this works

```js
import { DateFormatter } from "./../../../../src/util/formatter/date-formatter";
```

this doesn't

```js
import { DateFormatter } from "src/util/formatter/date-formatter";
```

no matter what I change in the `tsconfig.json` it always shows this error message

```js
Error: Cannot find module '<file in my project>' from '<path to my test file>'
```

[image: Error message in cypress test runner]

### Reproducible example

To test this out I followed the instructions of a minimal [Cypress - TypeScript example](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/cypress) until the section [Tip: Sharing code between UI and test](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro-1/cypress) and it works just fine but if I replace relative with absolute paths it doesn't work anymore.

Here is a [github non-working example](https://github.com/DarkMikey/cypress-typescript-absolute-path-example)

### EDIT: Additional research

I've found this cypress issue [typescript compilerOptions not reflected](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7188) and this [comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7188#issuecomment-633198710) that shows that cypress is ignoring tsconfig.json `complierOptions` and therefore it's not possible to add `baseUrl` and `paths` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Fixed in [Cypress@5.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#5-0-0)

### Old

This is actually a bug in Cypress and will be fixed soonish according to this [comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7188#issuecomment-665034985)

> A user's tsconfig.json is not loaded by Cypress. This is covered by this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7006) and is being addressed by this [PR](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/7982), which will be released in v5.0 in the near future. [...] it will fix any issues with baseUrl/paths config.